# iPhone ANT+ bicycling apps that can import a GPS track?

Tags: gps, iphone

Does anyone know if any of the popular iPhone ANT+ bicycling apps have the ability to *import* a GPS track?

I'd like to start exploring some of the local trails/routes a bit - I've got .gpx tracks for some, but don't know of any iPhone apps that will both allow the import of the file AND feature any sort of ANT+ tie-in. I normally use digifit with speed/cadence and HRM sensors... I've got a GPS track of where I *AM*, but really wish there were some sort of approximate "turn by turn" for following some of the trails/routes, especially the urban ones that are not clearly marked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Motion-X](http://news.motionx.com/category/motionx-gps/) as my tracking app and it can certainly import GPX and then navigate from it. It supports some ANT+ (at least HRM).

Additionally the OpenStreetMap wiki has a good [list of iOS apps](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Apple_iOS) comparing their functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [cyclemeter](http://www.abvio.com/cyclemeter/) directly from safari or email within your iphone.

Comment: I use this application when I cycle. You can e-mail the .gpx file to yourself as an attachment of as a url.